# how to handle a null value in JSON data member for DateTime

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am receiving a JSON file from my service that looks like this:

```
{
  "body": {
    "assignedTo": "aa",
    "message": "aaa",
    "submittedOn": 1506703098946,
    "completedOn": null,
    "submittedBy": "web-user",
    "completedBy": null,
    "isSelected": false,
    "name": "aaa"
  }
}
```

The value of 'completedOn' is defined as a `DateTime` in my class but what I am getting from the server is null. Is there a way to handle that?

Here's my class structure:

```
[DataContract]
    public class FamilyTask
    {
        private static readonly DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "assignedTo")]
        public string assignedTo { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "message")]
        public string message { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "submittedBy")]
        public string submittedBy { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "completedBy")]
        public string completedBy { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public DateTime submittedOn { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "submittedOn")]
        private long submittedOnTicks {
            get { return (long) (submittedOn - unixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds; }
            set { submittedOn = unixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(value); }
        }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public DateTime completedOn { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "completedOn")]
        private long completedOnTicks
        {
            get { return (long)(completedOn - unixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds; }
            set { completedOn = unixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(value); }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I did try adding a nullable to the `public DateTime? completedOn{get;set;}` but that causes this issue:

[image]

[image]

Edit2:

I implemented the nullable class and a null check but I am still getting this:

[image]

Comment: Make it nullable.

Comment: Use `public DateTime? completedOn {get;set;}`

Comment: I did try making it nullable. Please see above.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Please see my edit. I have implemented the nullable and null check as you suggested but it's still failing to parse.

Comment: You will need to nullcheck your setter as well(value).

Comment: but long cannot be null so value will never be null. Do I check if value is long.MinValue?

Comment: I've edited again...

Comment: @JOSEFtw this is awesome! That makes sense, just skip the setter all together. It will be set to null by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it nullable by adding a questionmark like this:

```
public DateTime? CompletedOn { get; set;}
```

You can then check if it has a value by using .HasValue. The actual value can be accessed with .Value.

Regarding your edit, you need to use .Value here(you will need to check for null!)

```
private long completedOnTicks
{
    get
    { 
         if(completedOn.HasValue)
         {
              return (long)(completedOn.Value - unixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds; }
         }

         // completedOn is null, return something reasonable
         return long.MinValue;
    }
    set { completedOn = unixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(value); }
}
```

If the webservice returns a DateTime, Why are you not just doing it like this?

```
[DataMember(Name = "completedOn")]
public DateTime? CompletedOn { get; set;}

// completedOnTicks is not needed anymore?
private long completedOnTicks
{
        get
        { 
             if(CompletedOn.HasValue)
             {
                  return (long)(CompletedOn.Value - unixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds; }
             }

              // CompletedOn is null, return something reasonable
             return long.MinValue;
        }
}
```

If it does not return a DateTime but instead a long, just make your long nullable as well.

Comment: The webservice returns a long. Your answer with removing a setter from `completedOnTicks` works fine! Thank you again!

Comment: It's best case to have a plain DTO class and then map the DTO to a Domain object, I think it would be better if you removed your DateTime? completedOn property and then created a long? completedOn instead. Then when you have all your data from the web service, just map it to a domain object.